# `fft` not returning what it should

Tags: python, numpy, fft

I am trying to perform Fourier transform using numpy's `fft` as follows:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

t = np.linspace(0,1, 128)
x = np.cos(2*np.pi*t)

s_fft = np.fft.fft(x)
s_fft_freq = np.fft.fftshift(np.fft.fftfreq(t.shape[-1], t[1]-t[0]))
plt.plot(s_fft_freq, np.abs(s_fft))
```

The result I get is

[image]

which is wrong, as I know the FT should peak at `f = 1`, as the frequency of the `cos` is `1`.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It looks like you've got some trouble understanding the math behind a FFT. You should look into topics like *Nyquist-frequency* and *spectral leakage*.

Comment: Have you tried to increase max(t)? Just one oscillation might not be enough to determine the frequency.

Comment: Fft is accurate if frequency*total_time is large. In your case this number is approximately one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are only applying `fftshift` to the x-axis labels, not the actual FFT magnitudes - you just need to apply `s_fft = np.fft.fftshift(np.fft.fft(x))` too.

Answer (score 3):

There are 2 or 3 things you have gotten wrong:

1. The FFT will peak at two positions for a pure real-valued frequency. This is the plus and minus frequencies. The only way to get a single peak in the Fourier domain is by having a complex valued signal (or having the trivial DC component).
2. (if with f, you mean frequency index) When using the DFT, the number of samples will determine how many frequency components you have. At the highest frequency index, you are always close to the per-sample oscilation: (-1)^t
3. (if with f, you mean amplitude) There are [many definitions of the DFT](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/32039/what-is-the-relationship-between-different-definitions-of-fourier-transform#32043), affecting both the forward and backward transform. This will affect how the values are interpreted when reading the spectrum.